# Javascript personality quiz trouble using 'this' and data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a click through personality quiz using pure javascript for a uni assignment. I have a bunch of divs laid out in order that they should appear. Each question has a list of 4(or so) answers that relate to a different personality type. I intend to keep an array of objects to tally each selected answer and provide a breakdown of personality types at the end.

I'm currently stuck on the function to;

1. record the selected data and add it to the answers array,
2. hide the current question div and
3. display the next question div

**HTML**:

```
<div class="question" id="q1"  data-next="q2">
  <h2>Question 1:</h2>
  <p>Which of the following is your favourite movie? </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Karate Kid</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Wall-E</li>
    <li data-score="Pirate">Pirates of the Caribbean</li>
    <li data-score="Zombie">Dawn of the Dead</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
  <h2>Question 2:</h2>
  <p>A building is on fire and you hear a child's screaming for help from the third floor window. Do you: </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Mysteriously disappear and re-appear with the children</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Run in and save the child on the second floor, because i'm made of metal and fire won't hurt me!</li>
    <li data-score="Pirate">Dress up as a pirate and loot the surrounding neighbourhood, including the bank?</li>
    <li data-score="Zombie">Eat all the brains. Nom nom uuuuggghhh.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 // Create a listener for clicks on the 'start the quiz' button on the front page. 
    document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz () {
    document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

// Create an array object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
var answerData = [
    {name: "Ninja" , score: 0},
    {name: "Robot" , score: 0},
    {name: "Pirate" , score: 0},
    {name: "Zombie" , score: 0} ]

// Get all of the .buttons elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
// Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .buttons
for (var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    // When an element with .buttons is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
    buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
    }

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked() {
    // Get the current element's data-score value
    var selectedType = this.dataset.score;
    // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
    answerData["selectedType"].score++;
    // Hide the current question div
    this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    // Work out what the next question div is
    var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
    // Display the next question element
    document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
}
```

Fiddle with what I've done so far https://jsfiddle.net/funkefiddle/e1za0gtr/1/

For some reason I decided that data-score was a good place to make a connection between the clickable answer element and actually keeping a track of it. However, obviously my code isn't actually working. Firefox console is showing "this.dataset.score is undefined".

```
var selectedType = this.dataset.score.value;
answerData["selectedType"].score++;
```

Please halp.

Also - I have no idea if the code to display the next element in the series will work yet as my error checking hasn't made it that far yet. I just wrote what my brain suggested might work.

Edit: Got rid of the .value because I don't know why I had it there in the first place. 
Also changed the last line to make nextQuestion a variable instead of a string. The questions now show/hide in progression (when I comment out the answerData line.

I guess that means I'm stuck on the line that I want to increase the array value for the selected answer type.

```
answerData[selectedType].score++ ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to correct:

1. As you bound the handler to the `ol` elements, `this` refers to that element. The *score* data does not exist on that element. Instead you can use the event object's `target` to know the element that was actually clicked on.
2. When retrieving the value of the `data-score` attribute, you should just refer to `dataset.score`, not `dataset.score.value`
3. `answerData["selectedType"]` has two problems: it addresses `answerData` not as an array, but as object; and "selectedType" is a literal, which will not become the value of the variable with the same name. Remove the quotes, and change your data structure `answerData` to a plain object, instead of an array:

   ```
   var answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
       "Ninja": 0,
        "Robot": 0,
       "Pirate": 0,
       "Zombie": 0};
   ```
4. The argument to `getElementById` should not start with a hash. You need to pass the *id* as such, without hash.
5. ... and you need to finish the other questions with the Ninja thing... ;-)

Here is the code with these corrections -- I did not complete point 5 entirely:

```js
// Create a listener for clicks on the 'start the quiz' button on the front page. 
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz () {
    document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

// Create an array object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
var answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
    "Ninja": 0,
     "Robot": 0,
    "Pirate": 0,
    "Zombie": 0};

// Get all of the .buttons elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
// Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .buttons
for (var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    // When an element with .buttons is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
    buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
    }

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked(e) {
    var target = e.target; // 1. `this` is parent, need target
    console.log(target);
    // Get the current element's data-score value
    var selectedType = target.dataset.score;   // 2. score is the value
    // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
    console.log(selectedType);
    answerData[selectedType]++;  // 4. after change of structure
    // Hide the current question div
    this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    // Work out what the next question div is
    var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
    // Display the next question element
    console.log(nextQuestion);
    document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block"; // no hash!
}
```

```css
.question, #result {
    display: none;
    }

.button li {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button li:hover {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    background-color: #555;
}

#intro, .question, #result {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#beginquiz:hover {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
  <h2>Welcome to Ewan L's Assignment 1 Quiz.</h2>
  <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q1"  data-next="q2">
  <h2>Question 1:</h2>
  <p>Which of the following is your favourite movie? </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Karate Kid</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Wall-E</li>
    <li data-score="Pirate">Pirates of the Caribbean</li>
    <li data-score="Zombie">Dawn of the Dead</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
  <h2>Question 2:</h2>
  <p>A building is on fire and you hear a child's screaming for help from the third floor window. Do you: </p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Mysteriously disappear and re-appear with the children</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Run in and save the child on the second floor, because i'm made of metal and fire won't hurt me!</li>
    <li data-score="Pirate">Dress up as a pirate and loot the surrounding neighbourhood, including the bank?</li>
    <li data-score="Zombie">Eat all the brains. Nom nom uuuuggghhh.</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q3" data-next="q4">
  <h2>Question 3:</h2>
  <p>Where do you call home?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">A magical castle in the English countryside </li>
    <li data-score="Robot">A dark and secret cave in the distant mountains</li>
    <li>A secluded hut in the woods</li>
    <li>34 Tooranimble St, Kanimboolaga NSW</li>
    <li>The sea is my only home. Man the rigging you scurvy sea dog! YARR</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q4" data-next="q5">
  <h2>Question 4:</h2>
  <p>What is your favourite letter?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">A</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>Rrrr</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q5" data-next="q6">
  <h2>Question 5:</h2>
  <p>What is your favourite music?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Rrrr and B</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Robo-boogie</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q6" data-next="q7">
  <h2>Question 6:</h2>
  <p>If you were a pirate, would you:</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Lead a quiet life of solace and penance</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">Loot and plunder</li>
    <li>Wear an eye-patch</li>
    <li>Have one leg</li>
    <li>All of the above, except for number 1. </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q7" data-next="result">
  <h2>Question 7:</h2>
  <p>Do you like pirates?</p>
  <ol class="button">
    <li data-score="Ninja">Yes</li>
    <li data-score="Robot">No</li>
    <li>I'm just here for the free cookies</li>
    <li>How did i get this far into the quiz? What am i doing with my life??</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <h2>HAHA we fooled you matey. You're a pirate through and through.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I kid you not as I read this reply my spotify playlist started playing "Come and get your love" from the Guardians of the Galaxy awesome mix vol.1

Thanks a bunch for the response. I had never even heard of event targets before now.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know what next song you want to hear :P

Answer (score 1):

answerData is an array. But you are using it as if it is a Object with properties. You can either change the array to a object with the property names or you will have to map the name property and get the index of the selected value.

Either change the array to a object like so:

```
var answerData = {
    "Ninja": { score: 0 },
    "Robot": { score: 0 },
    "Pirate": { score: 0 },
    "Zombie": { score: 0 }
}
```

And a quick change from 'selectedType' string to the actual object:

```
answerData[selectedType].score++; // remove quote around selectedType
```

Or keep it as a array but update the way you are updating it by first creating an array that maps the names:

```
var answerDataNames = answerData.map(function(obj){
    return obj.name;
}
```

Your code will then look like this:

```
 // Get the current element's data-score value
var selectedType = this.dataset.score;
// Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
var selectedIndex = answerDataNames.indexOf(selectedType);
answerData[selectedIndex].score++;
```

Comment: Object with properties is definitely what I had in mind. 
I updated the JS to:
function buttonClicked() {
 var selectedType = this.dataset.score;
 answerData[selectedType].score++;
 this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
 var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
 document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
}

However I'm still getting a console error "TypeError: answerData[selectedType] is undefined"

Comment: @Funkyflow selectedType is probably undefined. That solution is answered by trincot. So all you have to do is combine that snippet of code from his portion with mine